# Need help for my html contact form for uni

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, contacts

Basically I am a huge beginner on web design and i need help identifying where I actually put my email in this contact form as the recipient I have looked at the code like 5 times and I know i probs have missed it somewhere but could someone tell me where in the code i put my email address as the recipient!!

Heres the link to the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/VkeP5/

Heres my html the rest is on jsfiddle

```
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>{name} Portfolio - {Page Name}</title>

    <!-- grabs the latest jquery script from google -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/processForm.js"></script>        

    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

    <div id="contactForm">

        <div id="contactForm_messageToUser">Your message has been sent.<br />We will be in contact shortly.</div>

        <!-- The form that the user will fill out. -->
        <form id="contactForm_form">

            <table>

                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <input id="user_name" name="user_name" type="text" value="" />

                        <div id="user_name_message" class="errorMessage">
                            Please enter your name.
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <td>
                        <input id="user_phone" name="user_phone" type="text" value="" />

                        <div id="user_phone_message" class="errorMessage">
                            Please enter a valid phone number.
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <td>
                        <input id="user_email" name="user_email" type="text" value="" />

                        <div id="user_email_message" class="errorMessage">
                            Please enter a valid email address.
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>Message</th>
                    <td>
                        <textarea id="user_message" name="user_message"></textarea>

                        <div id="user_message_message" class="errorMessage">
                            Please enter your message.
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <td>
                        <input id="user_submit" name="user_submit" type="submit" value="Send your message" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>

        </form>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: 'Java' is to 'JavaScript' as 'Car' is to 'Carpet'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to send the information submitted through the form to your email address, this is what you need to change in processEmail.php:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['user_submit']) && $_POST['user_submit'] != ''){
        $body = "Name: " . $_POST['user_name'] . "<BR>";
        $body.= "Phone: " . $_POST['user_phone'] . "<BR>";
        $body.= "Email: " . $_POST['user_email'] . "<BR>";
        $body.= "Message: " . $_POST['user_message'];

        $to = "Your Email Address";
        $subj = "User Form Submitted";
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers.= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
        $headers.= "From: ".$_POST['user_email']."\n";

        if (mail($to,$subj,$body,$headers)){
            echo "<h2>Message Sent</h2>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<h2>Unable to submit the form, please recheck the details.</h2>" ;
        }
   }
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to rely on the browser to use outlook or the user's client to send email,

use

```
<form action="mailto:myemail@domain.com" method="post">
```

Although this is not a good idea, since, most people just use webamil. So you need a server to forward the email for you. u need to write code in php, asp, java or something, or use services that will allow you to forward emails

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the email address to which the completed form will be sent, it's not here. The form is submitted by an AJAX call to a server-side script `processEmail.php` - look there for the address

Comment: ok well no idea where that is, the teacher hasnt provided the file, all ive got is what ive posted